# what is integral of this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, limits, special-functions

Let $f(x)$ be an arbitrary continuous function, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{1+n\cdot f(x)^2}$$
then what is anti-derivative of this:
$$
\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\right)\cdot\tanh\left(n\cdot f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)dx = ?
$$ 
or
$$
\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\right)\cdot\tanh\left(n\cdot f(x)\right)\cdot\tanh\left(n\cdot\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)dx = ?
$$
Both integral equals(in the limit when n goes to infinity).
Also we know that $\int \left(\frac{d}{dx}g(x)\right)dx = g(x)$ and $\int \left(n.f(x).\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)dx = n\cdot\frac{f(x)^2}{2}$

Comment: Let $u=2[1+nf(x)^2]$. Observe that $g(x)=2/u$ so that $g'(x)dx=-2du/u^2$.  Note also that $u'=nf(x)f'(x)$.  We can now write the first integral as $-2\int\frac{\tanh(u')}{u^2}\;du$. Not sure that helps though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to expect a closed form answer for this problem; take $n=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$, and ask your favorite CAS to do your first antiderivative. Wolfram Alpha states that there is no closed form, and while that is not a proof, it is good enough for me (at least until you can demonstrate that there should be a closed form somehow).